# How do I echo rows that have a specific ID in it from Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So first off my database table is set up like this:

> ### id | userid | amount | date | status
>
> ### 1 | 10     | 25.00  | 2017-09-12 | None

and I want to to echo out all the rows that include userid 10 into a html table. I have tried this:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$userinfo= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE userid = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($userinfo) or die();

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<tr>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['id'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['amount'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['date'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['status'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

and nothing shows up.

Comment: The `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated in PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) :)

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) , use $userinfo instead of $query

Comment: its still not showing anything on the table?

Comment: where is your connection?? how are you connecting to database in this file? and what is $mysqli ?

Comment: i have a dbconnection in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

1 . use $userinfo instead of $query `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))`

2 . Change `$mysqli->query` to `mysqli_query`.

3 . Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

//mysqli_connect("host","username","password","dbname") 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
$sql="SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE userid = '.$id.'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr>
  <td>' .$row['id'].'</td>
  <td>' .$row['amount'].'</td>
  <td>' .$row['date'].'</td>
  <td>' .$row['status'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: this still doesnt return anything on the table

Comment: please try `print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($userinfo));` and give me output which you get on screen.

Comment: Database connection is also missing.

Comment: i still dont recieve an output

Comment: Please check the table and get id. Like $_GET['id'] is 1 then please check record exist in table or not.

Comment: Please change `mysqli_fetch_array($userinfo)` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)`

Comment: still nothing on the table

Comment: <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$userinfo= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE userid = $id");

echo '<tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)){
  echo '
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['id'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['amount'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['date'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['status'].'</td>
        ';
}
echo '</tr>';
?>

Comment: print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($userinfo)); before while loop and give me return array output

Comment: Thanks for accept the answer. Hope this will help you. @awesomexbox3

Answer (score 0):

you mixing mysqli with mysql and object oriented style with Procedural

use object oriented as below

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$userinfo= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE userid = $id");  
echo '<table>';

while($row = $userinfo->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<tr>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['id'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['amount'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['date'].'</td>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['status'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: that still doesnt return anything in the table

Comment: var_dump($userinfo) and see what it is returning

Comment: var_dump($userinfo); die(); see it is returning true or false

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $mysqli = new \mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
   $userinfo= $mysqli->query("SELECT id, amount, date, status FROM invoices WHERE userid = $id");

  echo '<table>';
  if ($userinfo->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $userinfo->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>
           <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['id'].'</td>
           <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['amount'].'</td>
           <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['date'].'</td>
           <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['status'].'</td>
        </tr>';
     }
  }
  else {
     echo "0 rows returned";
  }
  echo '</table>';
?>
```

Also just me being annoying but don't use * in your select statement. Always list the fields even if you want every single one. You should also be using prepared statements.

Comment: it also doesnt return anything in the table

Comment: Add the else clause and let me know if anything is printed. Judging from the other comments on here it sounds like there are no results;

Comment: yeah there are no results

Comment: Okay, did it echo the above message? If so the error is with your statement or the id variable.

Comment: oh i receive this error in my log "[28-Jun-2017 01:02:03 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on null in /home/username/public_html/network/users/invoices.php on line 53
"

Comment: Okay, where does $mysqli come from? You didn't show that in your above code.

Comment: Add the following before the query and change localhost, username, password and database.
$mysqli = new \mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');